# Sufficient statistic vector of single parameter?

Tags: poisson-distribution, hidden-markov-model, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

Can the sufficient statistic for a single parameter be a vector?

In my case, I am finding the sufficient statistics for the Poisson parameter in a HMM mixture. The parameter enters my log likelihood through:

$$\sum_{t=0}^T \ldots y_t q_t^i r_t^j \log(\lambda_{i,j}) - [\lambda_{i,j}]^{(q_t^i r_t^j)}$$

where $y_t$, $q_t^i$ and $r_t^j$ are random variables.

Would it be appropriate to say that the sufficient statistic of $\lambda_{i,j}$ is the following vector?

$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
\sum_{t=0}^T y_t q_t^i r_t^j\\
\sum_{t=0}^T q_t^i r_t^j\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title: **Yes, it is possible**. For an example [the normal parabola](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345876/conjugate-prior-distribution-for-a-specific-normal-curved-exponential-family) is nice. If you want more examples, curved exponential family's is a place to look!

If you want more information on your example, please provide more details ...