# Conjugate prior distribution for a specific (normal) curved exponential family

Tags: distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Is there a conjugate prior distribution in the model $\text{N}(\theta, \sigma^2=\theta^2)$, that is a normal distribution where the mean and standard deviation are equal ($\theta>0$)? (This question is related to [Conjugate for a special normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163014/conjugate-for-a-special-normal-distribution))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a conjugate distribution for $\theta$ in the model $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ iid $\text{N}(\theta, \theta^2)$ with $\theta>0$, but it is not a commonly named distribution. First find the likelihood of this "normal parabola" model, as it is called:
$$
L(\theta) = \prod_i^n \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\theta}e^{-\frac12\sum_i^n \left(\frac{x_i-\theta}{\theta} \right)^2}
$$
and (leaving out constants) this is proportional to
$$
L(\theta) \propto \theta^{-n} e^{-\theta^{-2}\sum_i x_i^2/2 + \theta^{-1}\sum_i x_i}
$$
Then we need a prior distribution on $\theta$ that can "absorb" these three factors. Using a form of bayes' theorem,
$$
\pi(\theta | x) \propto f(x | \theta) \pi(\theta) \\
= \theta^{-n} e^{-\theta^{-2}\sum_i x_i^2/2} e^{\theta^{-1}\sum_i x_i}\pi(\theta)
$$
So we need a prior density having some corresponding factors. We can try with a form which is a particular generalization of a generalized inverse gamma density
$$
   \pi(\theta) = K^{-1} \cdot \theta^{-\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{\beta}{\theta}-\frac{\gamma}{\theta^2}},\qquad \theta>0
$$
which is convergent for $\alpha>0,\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \gamma>0$. The proportionality factor $K$ has a very complicated form which will be given at the end.  This distribution will have a finite expectation for $a>1$ and a finite variance for $a>2$.

Using this we find that 
$$
\pi(\theta | x) \propto \theta^{-(n+\alpha)-1} e^{-(\beta-\sum_i x_i)/\theta } e^{-(\gamma+\sum_i x_i^2/2)/\theta^2}
$$
that is, the posterior has the same form as the prior.

I calculated the  constant $K$ with maple:

```
int( (theta^(-a-1))*exp(-b/theta - c/theta^2), theta=0..infinity ) assuming a>0,c>0,b,real;
```

which gives the following result:
$$
   1/2\,{\frac {{c}^{-a/2}}{\sqrt {\pi}} \cdot \\ \left( 1/4\,{\frac {{\pi}^{2}b}{
\sqrt {c}\cos \left( 1/2\,\pi\,a \right) \Gamma \left( 2-a/2 \right) }
 \left( 1/2\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}}-1+a \right) {\it LaguerreL} \left( 1
/2-a/2,1/2, \\ 1/4\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}} \right) }-1/8\,{\frac {{\pi}^{2}{
b}^{3}}{{c}^{3/2}\cos \left( 1/2\,\pi\,a \right) \Gamma \left( 2-a/2
 \right) }{\it LaguerreL} \left( 1/2-a/2,3/2,1/4\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}}
 \right) }+ \\ 1/2\,{\frac {{\pi}^{2}}{\sin \left( 1/2\,\pi\,a \right) 
\Gamma \left( 3/2-a/2 \right) } \left( 1/2\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}}+1
 \right) {\it LaguerreL} \left( -a/2,1/2,1/4\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}}
 \right) }- \\ 1/4\,{\frac {{\pi}^{2}{b}^{2}}{c\sin \left( 1/2\,\pi\,a
 \right) \Gamma \left( 3/2-a/2 \right) }{\it LaguerreL} \left( -a/2,3/
2,1/4\,{\frac {{b}^{2}}{c}} \right) } \right) }
$$
For the ${\it LaguerreL}$ function see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016771529190174P) in 1991 (!) about this problem, which got published in [Statistics and Probability Letters.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016771529190174P) And which recoups [Kjetil's solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/345877/7224) as the *generalised inverse Normal distribution*, which generalises the distribution of the inverse of a Normal random variable (not to be confused with the inverse Gaussian distribution). The density is expressed as
$$K(\alpha,\mu,\tau)\,|z|^{-\alpha}\exp\{-(z^{-1}-\mu)^2/2\tau^2\}\qquad\alpha>1,\ \tau>0$$
The paper also contains a representation of the normalising constant using confluent hypergeometric functions
$$K(\alpha,\mu,\tau)=\tau^{\alpha-1}e^{-\mu^2/2\tau^2} 2^{(\alpha-1)/2}
\Gamma((\alpha-1)/2){}_1F_1((\alpha-1)/2,1/2,\mu^2/2\tau^2)$$