# MLE of $\theta$ in $N(\theta, \theta^2)$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

> I have $X_i \overset{iid}{\sim} N(\theta, \theta^2)$, $\theta >0$, $i=1, \cdots, n$. I would like to find the MLE for $\theta$.

**My attempt**

I have a log likelihood $l(\theta) = -\frac{n}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac{\sum x_i^2}{2 \theta^2}  + \frac{\sum x_i}{\theta} - \frac{n}{2}$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} l(\theta) &= \sum x_i^2/\theta^3 - \sum x_i/\theta^2 \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} l(\theta) &= -3\sum x_i^2/\theta^4 + 2 \sum x_i/\theta^3 \\
&= \frac{-3 \sum x_i^2 + 2 \sum x_i \theta} {\theta^4}
\end{aligned}
$$

From $\sum x_i^2/n > \left( \sum x_i \right/n)^2$, I have when $0 < \theta < \frac{3}{2n} \sum x_i$, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} l(\theta) < 0$

So by setting $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} l(\theta) = 0$, I have $\hat{\theta}^{MLE} = \sum x_i^2 / {\sum x_i}$ when $\sum x_i >0 $,

But I can't proceed with the cases $\sum x_i < 0$ or $\frac{3}{2n} \sum x_i < \theta$.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345876/conjugate-prior-distribution-for-a-specific-normal-curved-exponential-family/345877#345877

Comment: Is this a homework question? Then you may want to tag it as [self-study]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That calculation doesn't look quite right.

Given the sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, likelihood function of $\theta$ is

\begin{align}
L(\theta\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=\frac{1}{(\theta\sqrt{2\pi})^n}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2\right]\quad,\theta>0
\end{align}

So the log-likelihood is of the form

$$\ell(\theta)=\text{constant}-n\ln\theta-\frac{1}{2\theta^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2$$

, so that

$$\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\theta}=\frac{-n}{\theta}-\frac{n\bar x}{\theta^2}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}{\theta^3}$$

Setting $\dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial\theta}=0$ and ignoring negative value of $\theta$ yields

$$\hat\theta=-\frac{\bar X}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}+\frac{\bar X^2}{4}}$$

Verify that this is indeed the MLE by checking $$\frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial\theta^2}\mid_{\theta=\hat\theta}<0$$

Finally we should arrive at

$$\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}}=-\frac{\bar X}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}+\frac{\bar X^2}{4}}\quad,\text{ if }\bar X>0$$

Comment: Since I'm not that good at calculus, I wonder if it's sufficient to check the second derivative is negative for the zero of the first derivative. Can we say the method yields a unique, global solution?

Comment: @moreblue Yes, $\frac{\partial^2\ell}{\partial\theta^2}\mid_{\theta=\hat\theta}<0$ is a sufficient condition for existence of maxima at $\theta=\hat\theta$ by the second derivative test. I think we can be sure that this maxima is in fact the global maxima.

Comment: To be sure that the maxima is global, I think to check $\lim_{\theta \to 0+}l(\theta) = -\infty$, $\lim_{\theta \to +\infty}l(\theta) = -\infty$ might be sufficient. Am I right?

Comment: @moreblue Drawing the log-likelihood might give a better indication to that end, although I am not sure if it is easily done. We also have the first partial derivative test at hand, so by checking the signs of $\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\theta}$, we can conclude regarding point of maxima.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\theta >0$ it suffices to show the numerator is always negative. Note that you only need to show it's negative at the MLE, not all values of $\theta$.

$$-3\sum x_i^2 + 2 \sum x_i \theta <0$$

Substitute in the MLE to obtain

$$-3 \sum_i x_i^2 + 2\sum_i x_i \frac{\sum_j x_j^2}{\sum_j x_j}$$

Cancel off the two sums on the right hand term

$$=-3\sum_i x_i^2 + 2 \sum_j x_j^2$$

$$=-1 \sum_i x_i^2 <0$$

Which is negative since every summand $x_i^2 >0$

Hence since the second derivative is negative at $\theta^{MLE}$, it's a local maximum of the likelihood function.

---

As pointed out by @StubbonAtom your derived MLE is incorrect. For example, examine the following R code with $\theta = 2$, the estimator you derived gives $\hat{\theta} \approx 4$.

```
x<- rnorm(10000,2,2)
sum(x^2)/sum(x)
[1] 4.009042
```